# Will member subobjects of local variables be moved too if returned from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, local-variables, move-semantics

The C++11 standard states that, if the conditions for copy elision are met (`§12.8/31`), the implementation shall treat a `return`ed local lvalue variable and function parameters, as an rvalue first (move), and if overload resolution doesn't succeed as detailed, shall then treat it as an lvalue (copy).

`§12.8 [class.copy] p32`

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, **and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue**. If overload resolution fails, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue. [ *Note:* This two-stage overload resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. *—end note* ]

Does this also include member subobjects? I tested with the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct traced{
  traced(){ std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }
  traced(traced const&){ std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
  traced(traced&&){ std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
};

struct X{
  traced t;
};

traced f(){
  X x;
  return x.t;
}

int main(){
  traced t = f();
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/x11Md)
And neither GCC 4.7 ToT nor Clang 3.1 ToT will display "move ctor", which leads me to believe that the standard doesn't include member subobjects.

Did I overlook something? Is my test code broken? What exactly causes the output to be as it is?

Comment: I don't think your tests proves that they can't. It may just show that it is hard for the compiler to confirm that the `criteria for elision` have been met as the highlighted section is only relevant if the compiler can confirm the criteria is valid.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I think I'm mixing up return-value-optimization and copy elision. I tweaked the code a little and got moves, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/SQqvH). I return x directly from `f()`, allowing RVO. And it uses `traced t = f().t;` which demonstrates the move. (I don't know if this helps!)

Comment: @Aaron. RVO is just one application of copy elision. :) A proper subset, so to say. Also, nice idea with the access after the return. Sadly, that is not applicable in my actual code. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When returning a subobject you can't elide its construction. Think of it this way: move and copy elision essentially amount to constructing the object in the place it would eventually be moved or copied to. This works for complete objects because there will be the appropriate space be set aside. It doesn't work with subobjects because you would construct the enclosing object. Even if this has the same size as the subobject, i.e. there is enough space, the enclosing object gets destroyed and may do funny things to the subobjects.

Effectively, this means that construction of the subject cannot be elided.

Comment: Which in turn means the whole paragraph of `§12.8/32` won't apply. I wonder why the standard doesn't simply say that, if the returned object is a local lvalue or a by-value func parameter, it should be moved, otherwise copied. Seems a bit strict to only rely on the eligibility of copy elision here. Any reason?

Comment: @Richard: Nice one. :) Maybe you could bring the last point in my comment up in the meetings if there's no special rational that would forbid that? :)

Comment: Richard could probably answer this way better sitting currently with his peers in the Core working group (I'm a Library guy, today sitting in Evolution, though). My guess is that the words are there to effectively delegate some of the rules to exiting specifications: these things are generally carefully worded to avoid inconsistencies which may be rather subtle. Also, you words don't quite apply: the idea of the words is, as far as I can tell, to find out whether the type can be moved or copied because this is a precondition for possibly being elided.

Comment: Hm, but moving of local variables in a return statement is specified in terms of copy elision, as far as I understood it...

Comment: Well, 12.8/32 is specifically about move or copy elision (the note even clarifies why the words are the way they are). In some sense it is even OK to have this apparently circular dependency because it isn't really: if move construction of local variables is defined terms of copy construction of local variable, there isn't any dependency! This paragraph is just extending the ability to elide construction to certain named objects and is careful to define it in a way consistent with out places, in particular the contraint that the elided constructor has to be accessible.

Comment: while what you say probably is true about NRVO, it is not necessarily true about the copy-to-move treatment. There is no techical problem in moving a subobject instead of copying it. Moving only a subobject and not the whole complete object is already required in code like `return X().t;`.

Comment: @Johannes: That's exactly my point, thanks for making it clearer than I was able to. :) Now I wonder if the rules for the copy-to-move treatment could be relaxed, to simply always move local variables instead of relying on whether copy elision is applicable.

Comment: @Xeo, do you mean something like "if elision doesn't apply, and we're about to return an object (or a subobject) which is going to be destroyed soon anyway (such as a local), then the compiler should pretend that the return expression was surrounded by `std::move`"? (As per my answer?)

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, that's basically what already happens, only that's it's completely restricted to cases where copy elision could apply.

Comment: @Xeo unfortunately the spec does not define the phrase "automatic object". The spec says that NRVO applies when the return expression is "the name of an automatic object". Now "x.t" is an automatic object, but is not a single name. Now if you say "struct X { traced t; traced f() { return t; } };", and "void a() { X x; x.f(); (new X)->f(); }", in the first call to "f" all conditions apply, in the second call to "f" the condition "automatic object" does not apply, if you take it to mean "object with automatic storage duration".

Comment: You can probably go on and say that the text probably means to include the implicit "this" transformation, and that thus "return t;" is really "return (*this).t;", and hence the expression is not only a name anymore. But what is not explicitly written is usually not meant. Probably the safest bet is to bit-AND all possibilities and implement what others implemented already :)

Comment: I'm confused by the answer and subsequent comments. The OP seems to ask why the member sub-object isn't moved, instead of copied. The answer replies that copy/move elision cannot happen for the sub-object. Therefore, the questions remains, why is it copied instead of moved?

Comment: @haelix: The first paragraph of the question states the context: if move/copy construction can be elided, move construction may be applicable. Thus, the question is reduced to determine whether copy-elision is applicable when returning a subobject of an object. Since copy-elision isn't applicable (as stated in the answer) the subobject can't be [automatically] moved. To move the subobject you'd need to use `std::move()` (or something similar).