# Why am I seemingly allowed to copy std::unique_ptr in a return statement?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, unique-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Returning unique_ptr from functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions)

20.7.1.2 [unique.ptr.single] defines copy constructor like this :

```
// disable copy from lvalue
unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

So, why the following code compiles fine?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr< int > bar()
{
  std::unique_ptr< int > p( new int(4));
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  auto p = bar();

  std::cout<<*p<<std::endl;
}
```

I compiled it like this :

```
g++ -O3  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x kel.cpp
```

The compiler : g++ version 4.6.1 20110908 (Red Hat 4.6.1-9)

Comment: +1 for actually telling us what compiler you are using and how you compiled the code.  A rare sight on StackOverflow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the return statement, if you return a local variable, the expression is treated as an rvalue, and thus automatically *moved*. It is thus similar to:

```
  return std::move(p);
```

It invokes the `unique_ptr(unique_ptr&&)` constructor.

In the main function, `bar()` produces a temporary, which is an rvalue, and is also properly moved into the `p` in `main`.

Comment: No, subobjects are not automatically moved.

Comment: 12.8/31 has the exact example as in my question. Both you and Nawaz are right

Comment: @Xeo you're right. Wasn't there a question about that around? Yup, there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183087/will-member-subobjects-of-local-variables-be-moved-too-if-returned-from-a-functi

Comment: "*It is thus the same as: `return std::move(p);`*" Almost -- doesn't the latter inhibit (N)RVO?

Comment: @ildjarn Hmm, maybe. The standard wording describes it something like "when the criteria for copy elision are met, and it is an lvalue, it is treated as an rvalue for overload resolution." I don't know if that affects that. I'll reword anyway.

Comment: a local variable with a name is an lvalue, which is magically treated here as rvalue? never heard of that

Comment: Note that it is similar but not equivalent. An implicit move prevents copy elision.

Answer (score 19):

It is **not** *copied*, it is *moved*.

The return statement is equivalent to this:

```
return std::move(p);
```

Pedantically speaking, that is *semantically* equivalent. In reality, the compiler may optimize the code, eliding the call to the move-constructor. But that is possible only if you write it as:

```
return p; //It gives the compiler an opportunity to optimize this.
```

That is recommended. However, the compiler has no opportunity to optimize if you write this:

```
return std::move(p); //No (or less) opportunity to optimize this.
```

That is **not** recommended. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that copying from an lvalue is disabled, but "bar()" is an rvalue so it's OK.  You definitely need to be able to copy from rvalues.

Comment: And actually, it's the move from rvalue, not copy.