# Returning std::vector with std::move

Tags: c++, return, move-semantics, stdmove

I have a very basic question: is it a good idea to return a `std::vector<A>` using `std::move`? For, example:

```
class A {};
std::vector<A> && func() {
    std::vector<A> v;
    /* fill v */
    return std::move(v);
}
```

Should I return `std::map`, `std::list`.. etc... in this way?

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: Just return it by value.

Comment: `std::vector<A> & v;` ?? are you sure about that ?

Comment: Returning by value should be considered preferable. You will get return value optimization, whereas with moving you will incur a move.

Comment: I meant std::vector<A> v, without &

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You declare a function to return by r-value reference - this should almost never be done (if you return the local object by reference, you will end up with a dangling reference). Instead declare the function to return by value. This way the caller's value will be move constructed by the r-value returned by the function. The returned value will also bind to any reference.

Secondly, no, you should *not* return using an explicit `std::move` as this will prevent the compiler to use [RVO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/873025). There's no need as the compiler will automatically convert any l-value reference returned to an r-value reference if possible.

```
std::vector<A> func() {
    std::vector<A> v;
    /* fill v */
    return v; // 'v' is converted to r-value and return value is move constructed.
}
```

#### More info:

- [Using std::move() when returning a value from a function to avoid to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11817873/873025)
- [Is there any case where a return of a RValue Reference (&&) is useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5770253/873025)

Comment: This is not true until C++14. In C++11, when copy constructor is a deleted function, you need to explicitly std::move because RVO optimization is not guaranteed. For this reason, the compiler requires to have a copy constructor so that he will chose to copy when he decides he can't apply RVO

Comment: @HAL9000 This answer is about `std::vector`, `std::map`, and `std::list` (see the question), which neither have their copy ctor deleted. There are of course other objects that need an explicit `std::move`, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` etc. Using an explicit move represent resource ownership transfer for cases where copying is disallowed by design, not optimization of return values. And btw, basically all compilers supported RVO during the C++11 era, even though it was not guaranteed by the standard :)

Comment: @Snps I agree with the first part, I didn't pay enough attention to the question. For the RVO support, you didn't get the point: the language considers it an error when the copy constructor is a deleted function, because RVO support is not guaranteed, it doesn't matter if a compiler supports it.

Comment: @HAL9000 If the copy ctor was deleted by design and a user defined move ctor is present, then yes you would have to explicitly use `std::move` in C++11 if returning by value (if the move ctor is not user defined in this case, it would not be implicitly defined and you would get an error anyway). This all seems to be the exceptional case though.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. This will in fact prevent copy elision in some cases. There is even a warning in some compilers about it, called `-Wpessimizing-move`.

In agreement with other answers, just return it by value, changing the return type to simply be `std::vector<A>`, and the compiler will take care of calling the move constructor when needed.

You could take a look at this post I just found, which seems to explain it in much detail (although I haven't read it through myself):
https://vmpstr.blogspot.hu/2015/12/redundant-stdmove.html

Comment: While correct on the pessimising move, this answer is dangerous because it fails to address the fact that the returned reference will be dangling.

Comment: You don't think saying "just return it by value" kind of addresses this?

Comment: I consider it a tad too subtle: it can be interpreted as "just return the value without `std::move`" as well as "change the return type."

Answer (score 1):

Both gcc and clang compiler with enabled optimization generate same binary code for both case when you return local variable and when you write `std::move()`.
Just return a value.

But using `&&` and `noexcept` specifier is useful if you create moving constructor and moving `operator=` for your custom class

Comment: This has nothing to do with optimisations, really. The standard **requires** moving to be tried first in this case. Also, this answer is dangerous because it fails to address the fact that the returned reference will be dangling.