# move semantics behaviour on vector return

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I've been playing around with c++11 move semantics

In the code...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> GetNewVector()
{
  std::vector<std::string> newVec; 
  newVec.push_back(std::string("hello")); //(1)
  newVec.push_back(std::string("whey")); //(2)

  return newVec;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> vec = GetNewVector();
}
```

At point (1) the move constructor for the "hello" object is called when the object is moved into the vector.

At point (2) firstly the move constructor for "hello" is called again, (I'm assuming this is where the vector reallocates) and then the "whey" move constructor is called.

This is all as expected, however I was expecting the objects to be moved again when the vector is returned at the end of `GetNewVector()`, however the move constructor doesn't get called again. My guess is that RVO is taking place however as I'm running Visual Studio (2k10) in Debug mode I wasn't sure if this would happen?

Is it true that if RVO can be performed, then it will take precedence over using the move constructor?

Comment: what language is this? TString (CERN ROOT?) std::vector without specified type?

Comment: What you have is logically a copy, not a move.  To make it a move, you would have to do `return std::move(newVec)`.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Bad bad bad! Using `std::move` here would inhibit RVO and the standard already says that the compiler first has to try to move `newVec` and only if that fails copy it.

Comment: @Xeo: I didn't mean to imply that you would want to do that.

Comment: @JohanLundberg For some reason it seems to have deleted that bit. If I edit the question I can see the vector<TString> weird

Comment: Please highlight the code and use the `{}` button or ctrl-K to format it, this way, you won't run into HTML problems.

Comment: @VaughnCato: "To make it a move, you would have to do `return std::move(newVec)`." That doesn't seem like implying it, no, you're explicitly saying it. :P

Comment: @Xeo: I said "to make it a move" -- I didn't say that you would want to make it a move.

Comment: @VaughnCato: What I tried to explain in my comment is that `return a_local_variable;` will already perform a move, if NRVO isn't applied.

Comment: @Xeo: Ok, so what I said about it logically being a copy is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advantages of moves on containers would be severly crippled if it was specified that they moved element-wise.

Instead, they simply take the others inner guts, the pointers to the dynamically allocated array in `std::vector`s case, which leaves the elements where they are, making this a constant complexity operation. If you did element-wise moves, you'd be looking at a linear complexity operation.

> Is it true that if RVO can be performed, then it will take precedence over using the move constructor?

The standard is a bit restricted in this aspect, but yes, RVO (in general copy-elision, which also covers moves contrary to its name), will of course take precedence over anything else, since it's faster. :)

Note that automatic moves are only done in contexts where copy-elision *could* be done, but is not for whatever reason. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11492948/500104) for the more intricate details of automatic moves.

Comment: Ah okay, so the pointer to the raw array inside the vector is simply copied? makes sense, thanks

Comment: @TomP89: Well, copied, and then the old pointer is set to null, so when the old vector goes out of scope, it won't try to delete the array. :)